# trouble using strcat() to concatenate command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, strcat

I am trying to write a program for executing multiple programs from command line arguments. I start with concatenating the argv[x] strings I pass through calling the program into bigger strings that are separated by a semicolon.

I later want to execute this strings as separate child processes within a parent process.

But I am having trouble concatenating the arguments correctly.

my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char *wp = " ";
    for(int i=1; i < argc; i++){
            // if next argument is not a semicolon and is not null
            if((strcmp(argv[i],";") != 0) && (argv[i+1] != NULL) ){ 
                // concat this argument with whitespace
                strcat(argv[i],wp);
                // concat this argument with the next                
                strcat(argv[i],argv[i+1]);       
            }
            // go on with concatenating next arguments after semicolon if any, into new string ...
            }
       }
    // test results
    printf("\n%s",argv[1]);

    // go on with executing argv as a child process..
}
```

I call the above program with `./program ls -l -a . \; date`
and the output is: `ls  -a .`

Could someone explain why the complete series of arguments up until the semicolon is not shown? (`ls -l -a .`) Thank you

Comment: You can't `strcat` anything to `argv[i]`, you will overflow it. You need to copy it first to a buffer that has enough space.

Comment: Why do you think you need to concatenate the arguments? Just use a loop that calls `fork()` and `execlp()` with each argument as the program name argument.

Comment: You probably don't need to concatenate anything, but you may need to create a new array of pointers to strings. Show an example of your command line, and what commands you want to generate from it.

Comment: @mrOser5 And  what about a case when argv[i] itself contains the character ';'? Also show an example of source arguments and result strings.

Answer (score 3):

You should not write beyond the end of the strings pointed to by `argv`: there is no guarantee that memory can be written.  You should allocate an array with local storage or from the heap and construct the string there using `strcpy`, `strcat` or even `snprintf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    size_t total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        total += 1 + strlen(argv[i]);
    }
    char *str = malloc(total + 1);
    if (str == NULL) {
        perror("cannot allocate string");
        return 1;
    }
    size_t pos = 0;
    *str = '\0';
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], ";") && *argv[i]) {
            if (pos > 0)
                str[pos++] = ' ';
            pos += strlen(strcpy(str + pos, argv[i]));
        }
    }
    // test results
    printf("%s\n", str);

    // go on with executing argv as a child process
    //...
    
    // free memory
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: of course :)

Answer (score 0):

> I start with concatenating the argv[x] strings I pass through calling the program into bigger string

Problems include

**Insufficient buffer size**

Code fail to properly concatenate as the destination buffer is not specified to be large enough.

```
// strcat(argv[i],wp);  // Bad
```

OP's code instead experiences *undefined behavior* (UB).

---

What should be done instead depends on OP's larger unstated goal.