# Problem creating the qname of a DNS query in C

Tags: c, dns, winsock

I have been trying to create a DNS query in C but I am having trouble managing different data types and pointers,

I have the header build in the first position of a variable called ***buf***. Now I want to add the lookup host on the following positions of the array. The hostname to add to the query is passed through the parameter argv[1]

I have the following:

First I trimed the hostname by the delimiter "."

```
unsigned char *qname;
qname = &buf[sizeof(struct DNS_QUERY_HEADER)];
char *host = argv[1]; //my hostname
strcat((char*)host,".");
unsigned char *htrim = strtok(host, ".");`
```

Then I go through each of those trims, I store the size of it (the number of characters inside the label) and then store that part of the hostname before the "." for each iteration

```
if(htrim != NULL){
    while(htrim != NULL){
        *qname++ = htons(strlen((char*)htrim));
        for(int i = 0; i< strlen((char*)htrim); i++)
        {
            *qname++ = (htrim[i]);
        }
        htrim = strtok(NULL, ".");       
    }
}
```

Then I added the "/0" at the end of the query
`*qname++='\0';`

Finally the rest of the DNS message (type and class).

When I launch the program, the packet seems to be well formed. Header seems fine, Type and class ok. However, the hostname that is asking in the query is not google.com, for example, but either *watson.events.data.microsoft.com* or *root*. Therefore, I am guessing I am bulding the qname label wrong but this is the closest that I got.

Could anyone give me any hints of how should I stored the hostname in a DNS query or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't there a higher-level library that will automate this for you?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `strcat((char*)host,".");` (not sure if that's your only problem). The answers and comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76220615/trouble-using-strcat-to-concatenate-command-line-arguments might help

Comment: Yes, there is a library, but I have to build the packet itself as part of the requirement.

Comment: Thank very much for the input, it must not be the only problem, but it seems to build another packet with wapad.com instead of the watson query, so yes, I think the srtcat must have caused some issues. I put ir there for the root server, but it seems it is not needed. Thank you